# NSWindow drag regions should only be invalidated on the Main Thread

Tags: python

I am writing a python file that runs another python file. This file normally displays a tool made in Tkinter. However, it keeps giving me this error:

```
2022-04-23 09:16:13.748 Python[1881:28993] WARNING: NSWindow drag regions should only be invalidated on the Main Thread! This will throw an exception in the future. Called from (
        0   AppKit                              0x00007fff2e3497f0 -[NSWindow(NSWindow_Theme) _postWindowNeedsToResetDragMarginsUnlessPostingDisabled] + 371
        1   AppKit                              0x00007fff2e346ce1 -[NSWindow _initContent:styleMask:backing:defer:contentView:] + 1416
        2   AppKit                              0x00007fff2e3f2fa4 -[NSPanel _initContent:styleMask:backing:defer:contentView:] + 50
        3   AppKit                              0x00007fff2e346753 -[NSWindow initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 42
        4   AppKit                              0x00007fff2e3f2f59 -[NSPanel initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 64
        5   AppKit                              0x00007fff2ecdc61e -[NSSavePanel initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 97
        6   AppKit                              0x00007fff2ece4828 -[NSOpenPanel initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 151
        7   AppKit                              0x00007fff2e5df19a -[NSPanel init] + 75
        8   AppKit                              0x00007fff2ecdc5b6 -[NSSavePanel init] + 80
        9   AppKit                              0x00007fff2e9cdef5 +[NSSavePanel(Instantiation) _crunchyRawUnbonedPanel] + 81
        10  libtk8.6.dylib                      0x0000000154cd3a11 Tk_GetOpenFileObjCmd + 67
        11  libtcl8.6.dylib                     0x0000000154ac46dc TclNRRunCallbacks + 80
        12  _tkinter.cpython-38-darwin.so       0x0000000154a9d049 Tkapp_Call + 585
        13  Python                              0x000000010bb94112 cfunction_call_varargs + 290
        ............
        97  Python                              0x000000010bb93dfd PyVectorcall_Call + 109
        98  Python                              0x000000010bd025ba t_bootstrap + 74
        99  Python                              0x000000010bcb5589 pythread_wrapper + 25
        100 libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff685bed76 _pthread_start + 125
        101 libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff685bb5d7 thread_start + 15
)
```

When I run this file on its own, everything works perfectly fine. Both use the same python versions.